# Parse multiple log files for strings

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, logging, glob

I'm trying to parse a number of log files from a log directory, to search for any number of strings in a list along with a server name. I feel like I've tried a million different options, and I have it working fine with just one log file.. but when I try to go through all the log files in the directory I can't seem to get anywhere.

```
if args.f:
    logs = args.f
else:
    try:
        logs = glob("/var/opt/cray/log/p0-current/*")
    except IndexError:
        print "Something is wrong. p0-current is not available."
        sys.exit(1)

valid_errors = ["error", "nmi", "CATERR"]

logList = []
for log in logs:
    logList.append(log)



#theLog = open("logList")
#logFile = log.readlines()
#logFile.close()
#printList = []

#for line in logFile:
#    if (valid_errors in line):
#        printList.append(line)
#
#for item in printList:
#    print item


#    with open("log", "r") as tmp_log:

#       open_log = tmp_log.readlines()
#           for line in open_log:
#               for down_nodes in open_log:
#                   if valid_errors in open_log:
#                       print valid_errors
```

`down_nodes` is a pre-filled list further up the script containing a list of servers which are marked as down.

Commented out are some of the various attempts I've been working through.

```
logList = []
for log in logs:
    logList.append(log)
```

I thought this may be the way forward to put each individual log file in a list, then loop through this list and use `open()` followed by `readlines()` but I'm missing some kind of logic here.. maybe I'm not thinking correctly.

I could really do with some pointers here please.

Thanks.

Comment: logs, as return by glob, is already a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your last for loop is redundant because `logs` is already a list of strings. With that information, we can iterate through `logs` and do something for each `log`.

```
for log in logs:
    with open(log) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if any(error in line for error in valid_errors):
                #do stuff
```

The line `if any(error in line for error in valid_errors):` checks the `line` to see if any of the errors in `valid_errors` are in the line. The syntax is a generator that yields `error` for each `error` in `valid_errors`.

To answer your question involving `down_nodes`, I don't believe you should include this in the same `any()`. You should try something like

```
if any(error in line for error in valid_errors) and \
    any(node in line for node in down_nodes):
```

Comment: Ahh fantastic. I was over thinking it. It seems to work pretty well :) - I don't know about the end line though, any(error in line for error in valid_errors): -- is error a variable here? like i or line etc? I've not seen this before. any() is a useful thing to know. But I'd love to learn more if you have just a one or two line explanation? (I tried to upvote but it wouldn't let me)

Comment: @jonnybinthemix I added a little bit to the answer

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate you taking the time to do that for me :) - This is nice and simple, I like it.

Comment: If I wanted to adapt this to match two requirements, would I still use any() or all()? I guess all() would match have to match everything within valid_errors? But if I have another list called down_nodes, and I want to match any string in down_nodes AND any string in valid_errors... would it be easy to adapt the above for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to test this right now, but I wonder whether this line would do what I was looking for: `if any(error in line for error in valid_errors and down_nodes):` - What are your thoughts? I will be able to test it in a few hours.

Comment: @jonnybinthemix I think you want a logical OR not AND. You want to check to see if the error is any of the valid errors OR is any of the down nodes, right?

Comment: No, only want to see if a `down_node` has an error in `valid_errors` in the same line. So if node1 has a caterr or something, I need it to show a line like "node1 had a caterr in bank 5" or something. So I only care about the line if both ANY `down_node` and ANY `valid_error` coexist in the same line.

Comment: So you want to check to see if there is an error from `valid_errors` in the line and also check to see if one of the nodes from `down_nodes` is in the line?

Comment: Yes. For the line to be displayed, both have to be true. The line has to contain the server name from `down_nodes` and an error from `valid_errors` - When finished there are likely to be around 10 or so key words in `valid_errors` but the number of entries in `down_nodes` could be as many as 50.

Comment: @jonnybinthemix yeah then the update to my answer should be helpful, albeit ugly. You can modify it to more accurately fit your use case

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm going to play around it, but it seems to work well.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to find all logs:

```
import os
import fnmatch

def find_files(pattern, top_level_dir):
    for path, dirlist, filelist in os.walk(top_level_dir):
        for name in fnmatch.filter(filelist, pattern)
            yield os.path.join(path, name)
```

For example, to find all `*.txt` files in current dir:

```
txtfiles = find_files('*.txt', '.')
```

Then get file objects from the names:

```
def open_files(filenames):
    for name in filenames:
        yield open(name, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

Finally individual lines from files:

```
def lines_from_files(files):
    for f in files:
        for line in f:
            yield line
```

Since you want to find some errors the check could look like this:

```
import re

def find_errors(lines):
    pattern = re.compile('(error|nmi|CATERR)')
    for line in lines:
        if pattern.search(line):
            print(line)
```

You can now process a stream of lines generated from a given directory:

```
txt_file_names = find_files('*.txt', '.')
txt_files = open_files(txt_file_names)
txt_lines = lines_from_files(txt_files)
find_errors(txt_lines)
```

The idea to process logs as a stream of data originates from talk by David Beazley.

Comment: Ah, this is interesting thank you. I was using re.compile, re.match etc in another script I was working and did wonder whether it would be useful here. But I though since I want to display the whole log line, rather than parts of a given log line, I thought it would be easier just to dump out the lines. Essentially what I'm looking to do is for the script to find servers which are down, and then automatically check a few things to see if they're down for a common reason... then display on the screen the obvious ones.